# importing favourites from a old computer

Tags: bookmarks, import

I have a bunch of favorites (bookmarks) from a old machine in folders. How can I import them in windows 7? I don't have a proper exported backup.

Comment: What is the old OS? What browser? Do you have the other machine running at the same time?

Comment: its power supply is fried I had to pull the hardrive not sure what os, windows for sure. vista i think.

Comment: What browser? Internet Exxplorer, Safari, Firefox, Opera? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get access to the disk, the Windows favorite are stored in

```
c:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Favorites
```

or

```
c:\Users\<username>\Favorites
```

Depending on your version of Windows.  You can just copy the shortcut files to the same location on your new machine.